# ImageMagick convert svg to png

Tags: imagemagick

So i use this command to convert an svg file to png  :

```
convert ss.svg ss.png
```

But the output is a bit weird : 
[image: converted svg]

As you can see, xaxis and yaxis labels are on the top. Please help me output this image properly.

Comment: Can you provide us the svg image?

Comment: sure. here it is http://stagingbims.desaldata.com/ss.svg
that data came from a dump of google visualization api (interactive charts)

Comment: executed the same command on my laptop (Ubuntu Linux - 10.10 and ImageMagick version - 6.6.2-6 2010-12-02 Q16), but the output was exactly same as expected.

Comment: Which ImageMagick version do you use, r2b2?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the same and it seems to work, try to use my ImageMagick version: [image]
My settings:

1. Windows 7 (x86)
2. ImageMagick version

> c:\workspace2\01nerva\bin\client>convert.exe -version
>   Version: ImageMagick 6.7.5-4 2012-02-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
>   Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC

Answer (score 0):

This version works (on a Max OS X Lion) and provides the correct output:

```
/opt/local/bin/convert -version
  Version: ImageMagick 6.7.9-0 2012-08-17 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
  Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
  Features:  OpenCL HDRI
```

[image]