# VML to PNG/PDF (jsp)

Tags: jsp, png, raphael, vml

I have used raphael js for drwaing my flowchart in internet explorer 8. Now I want to export my drawing as image file. I found some answer but still confused what to do. Can anyone help me regarding this issue? A sample code would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting to PNG or PDF would involve converting the [VML2SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038740/how-to-convert-vml-to-png-using-php) using the stylesheets, the VML element, and [transformNode](http://ajaxian.com/archives/svg-on-ie-via-silverlight-via-xslt), then converting the SVG to PNG using a AJAX request which posts the image to a script which [creates the PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875807/convert-svg-to-pdf) or runs [imagemagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249963/imagemagick-convert-svg-to-png) and returns the result. The pseudocode is something like this:

```
svg = vml.transformNode(vml2svg)
$.post("/svg/png-or-pdf", svg, showImg);
```