# draw SVG with javascript online and in terminal

Tags: javascript, svg

I need to display some data online but I also would like to have nice plots as high-res files for printing. So far I was generating the plots as png, but now I am thinking on changing this to Javascript. This is mainly because I would like my plots to be dynamic.

The WWW part is looks relatively easy for me; I would grab data from a server with AJAX and plot on a webpage - I think SVG would be perfect for my needs. But how can I run the script from terminal with a file name as a parameter to get a myplot.svg (which of course will not be dynamic any longer) file that looks like the plot on the webpage?

Ideally I would like to have a single plotting subroutine in order to avoid duplicate code and to keep both versions looking the same.

So my questions are which framework should I use for SVG generation to make the terminal variant easy ?

Comment: Which operating system do you use? BTW I hope you know D3.js...

Comment: The system is ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageMagick to convert a SVG to png:

[ImageMagick convert svg to png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249963/imagemagick-convert-svg-to-png)

You can extract the generated SVG from a virtual DOM (with the same code as on your web page, perhaps with slightly differences regarding environment) when you use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom)

As mentioned in the comment I can recommend [D3.js - Data Driven Documents](http://d3js.org/) for generating SVG the easy way.

An alternative for Node.js and jsdom might be [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/).

Your task is not an easy one, but it's worth the effort. Good luck!